# Approximate an integral using Monte Carlo method

Tags: approximation, matlab, monte-carlo

I have a question on an assignment

> Calculate the value of the integral I = $\int_0^\pi sin^2(x)dx$ using the
>   Monte Carlo Method (by generating $ 10^4 $ uniform random numbers
>   within domain [0, π] × [0, 1]). First do the calculation using LCG
>   (Linear Congruent Generator) with a = $7^5$ , c = 0 and m = $2^{31}$ − 1,
>   then by Matlab’s build-in generator.

As I understand, I have to generate $ 10^4 $ uniform random numbers using the LCG algorithm with given parameters. But how I make sure they are within [0, π] × [0, 1] domain? Actually, what exactly "[0, π] × [0, 1] domain" means? LCG gives just random numbers between 0 and 1.

As I understand, I need to do something like this in C

```
double x = 1; // initial random number
// i is between 0 and Pi
for (double i = 0; i <= M_PI; i += M_PI/10000) {
    // generate the random number [0, 1] using LCG with the given params
    x = ((16807*x + 0) % 2147483647)/2147483647;
    if (sin(i)*sin(i) > x) {
        miss = miss + 1;
    }
    total = total + 1;
}
// calculate area based on the ratio of total vs. miss
```

why are we comparing $sin^2$ with a number between 0 and 1?

is it the other way around?

```
double x = 1; // initial random number
// i is between 0 and 10^4
for (double i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
    // generate the random number [0, Pi] using LCG with the given params
    x = ((16807*x + 0) % 2147483647)/2147483647 * M_PI;
    if (sin(i)*sin(i) > x) {
        miss = miss + 1;
    }
    total = total + 1;
}
// calculate area based on the ratio of total vs. miss
```

then why do we pass into $sin$ something that is between 0 and 10000?

I'm confused with how to apply the Monte Carlo method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate $2\times 10^4$ values, $10^4$ for $x\in [0,\pi]$ and $10^4$ for $y\in[0,1]$ and combine them as the coordinates of the points. Then test whether $y\leq \sin^2{x}$.

Comparing the area within the region between $[0,1]$ is to give it a bound. You can of course do it within $[0,2]$. However you choose the bound, you will need to multiply the ratio you get by the area of the whole region. If you choose $[0,1]$, you multiply the ratio by $\pi$. If you choose $[0,2]$, you multiply the ratio by $2\pi$.

Comment: That is weird. [I have used the right method, but my random variables approach zero.](http://pastebin.com/r0bkGqc8)

Comment: You cannot use the $r$ to divide by $m$ since you need to use the original $r$ later. You have to define another variable $u=r/m$ in each step.